# Huge decrease in file size on combining files in linux using python

Tags: python, linux, file, multiprocessing

I wrote a script which takes a folder of files, and combines them using the multiprocessing Pool library of python into files of max size 500MB. The script takes the list of files in the folder and divides it into 16 lists, and each is mapped to a process. In each process a combined temporary file is made with the set of files from each list. After all these 16 files are obtained, I sequentially combine these 16 files and delete the temp files.
 Im running this on a CentOS system with ext4 filesystem, and I passed a folder of size 930 MB, with 186147 files spread across 50 subfolders, it gave me a single file as output, of size 346 MB. I am confused how the file size could have decreased so much.

Do note that each of those 186147 files has an extra header at the start which is ignored during the final combined file creation, but a file with only the header is only 233 bytes.

In order to check if my script was correct I checked the total number of lines in the combined file(3083015) and it matched the sum of number of lines in the 186147 files(3269162) - the number of headers(186147). I also tried to cat the single file and the lines appear to be complete, I didnt go through the whole file though.

Is there something I am missing here?

This is the parallelized function that Im using:

```
curr_write_file_name = os.path.join(output_folder, str(list_index) + '_' + "00000.flows")
    curr_write_file = open(curr_write_file_name, 'w')
    curr_write_file.write(header)
    curr_write_count = 1
    for curr_file in file_list:
        print('Processing', curr_file)
        netflow_read = open(curr_file, 'r')
        for index, line in enumerate(netflow_read):
            if index == 0:
                continue
            else:
                curr_write_file.write(line)
                if os.stat(curr_file).st_size >= 500000000:
                    curr_write_file.close()
                    curr_write_file_name = os.path.join(output_folder, str(list_index) + '_' + str(curr_write_count).zfill(5) + '.flows')
                    curr_write_file = open(curr_write_file_name, 'w')
                    curr_write_count = curr_write_count + 1
                    curr_write_file.write(header)
        netflow_read.close()
```

And this is the corresponding main:

```
if __name__=='__main__'
    dataFileList = []
    for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(str(sys.argv[1])):
                # Since the filtering occurs parallel, sorting the files has no benefit
            dirNames.sort()
            fileNames.sort()
            dataFileList = dataFileList + [os.path.join(dirPath, fileName) for fileName in fileNames if fileName.endswith('.flows')]
        noOfProcesses = os.cpu_count()*2  # To create a maximum of no_of_cores*2 processes
        process_pool = mp.Pool(noOfProcesses)  # To create a parallel pool of noOfProcesses processes
        file_split_number = int(len(dataFileList)/noOfProcesses)
        dataFile_list_of_lists = [(dataFileList[x:x+file_split_number], x) for x in range(0, len(dataFileList), file_split_number)]
        process_pool.map(worker_process_combine_set, dataFile_list_of_lists)    # To map the processes to the files in the list and split them
        stage_1 = time.time()
        print('Completed first stage combining successfully in', stage_1 - start_time, 'seconds')
        process_pool.close()
        process_pool.join()
        # sequential combining
        finalFiles = combine_final()
        print('Completed combining files successfully in', time.time() - start_time, 'seconds')
```

Comment: How do you get the size of your folder (you mean directory don't you)?

Comment: @Anthon yes I meant directory. I used du -sh data_directory

Comment: Well `du -sh` doesn't show the combined size of the files. Just how much disk size the files take combined (including any overhead). If you using a filesystem without tail-packing that kind of difference is to be expected with that amount of files. Please edit your post to include information on which filesystem type (ext4, btrfs, reiserfs, xfs, etc) you are using

Comment: @Anthon it is ext4. Is there any way to check the actual combined size of the files?

Comment: Is this python script the equivalent of `cat source_dir/**/*(.) > result_file` in zsh? Or maybe even `cat source_dir/* > result_file`?

Comment: @ArjunBalgovind ext4 doesnt' do tail packing, so as Błotosmętek answered you'll have half a block of space on average per file "waste". `find . -type f -exec wc -c {} +` could work unless the commandline becomes too long. If that is the case use pythons os.walk() and add the filesizes yourself (you can ask a different question on [so] about that

Comment: @Anthon thanks alot for the help. I didn't know anything about these block sizes and such things. I've been enlightened now :D.

Comment: @marcelm no, I also have to delete the first line in each of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post has been written for [ext4 filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) that is the default filesystem for the most distributions on Linux, you can check your current filesystem with:

```
df -T / | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1
```

The following explanations could be not applicable for other filesystems, even if a lot of filesystems work like it (no support for [block sub-allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation)).

The **size of a file** and the quantity of **disk space** allocated by this file are 2 different notions. The unity for your disk storage mounted with a specific filesystem is the **filesystem's block size**. Each file is stored by using a certain number of blocks. But the **last block** is not always full, your filesystem allocates this remaining space to respect this rule. And the data of a file occupies a space which represents a number multiple of the size of a block. That is why if **you convert several files into a single file by concatenation, you save disk's space**.

For your case, converting `186147` files into a single file: if you consider that number of bytes in the last block is not really used and follows a uniform law, you save on average `186147*sizeof(block)/2` bytes and at most `186147*sizeof(block)` bytes for the disk storage **without counting the saved metadata and overhead filesystem of each file**.

For the most filesystems, the size of a block is 4KB, that is to say 4096 bytes. Here you save on average `(4096/2)*186147//(1024**2) = 363MB` and at most `4096*186147//(1024**2) = 727MB`.

See your file system's block size by executing:

```
device=$(df -T / | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1)
dumpe2fs "${device}" | grep 'Block size'
```

Test it with:

```
echo 'a' > filea.txt; echo 'b' > fileb.txt; more *; ls -sh *
```

Output:

```
::::::::::::::
filea.txt
::::::::::::::
a
::::::::::::::
fileb.txt
::::::::::::::
b
4,0K filea.txt 4,0K fileb.txt
```

Then:

```
cat * > file.txt; more *; ls -sh *
```

Output:

```
::::::::::::::
filea.txt
::::::::::::::
a
::::::::::::::
fileb.txt
::::::::::::::
b
::::::::::::::
file.txt
::::::::::::::
a
b
4,0K filea.txt  4,0K fileb.txt  4,0K file.txt
```

The size of `file.txt` is `4KB` not `8KB = sizeof(fileb.txt) + sizeof(filea.txt)`.

If you create a file of 4097 bytes, 2 filesystem's blocks will be allocated. See:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt  bs=1  count=4097 &> /dev/null
ls -s --block-size=1 file.txt
```

Output:

```
8192 file.txt
```

The size of file.txt is `8192 bytes = 2*sizeof(filesystem_block)` not `4097 bytes`.

Comment: I have been using tailpacking filesystems on Linux since the previous millenium and for those the above is not true. The OP is using `ext4` for which this does apply but you should include information in your post that this is not applicable  for all filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

What is your filesystem's block size? Because, you see, there is some unused space at the end of the last block, on average that would be half a block, and if you multiply that by the number of files (186147) this might amount to several hundred megabytes…

Comment: That might well be the cause for the discrepancy, but only on filesystems that don't support [tail-packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation)

Comment: I don't know anyone still using Reiser and btrfs is generally considered an adventure for the brave. And since OP mentioned Linux, it was highly unlikely he was using UFS2. But yes, technically, not all filesystems suffer from internal fragmentation.